# Sitecore Cortex calculate Average/Min/Max in projection framework

Tags: cortex

I store custom outcomes in interaction repository and want to build projection model for my machine learning model.

```
public class PurchaseInvoiceOutcome
{
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

I need grouped data that looks like:

**ProductId**: product identifier

**Year**: grouping by year

**Month**: grouping by month

**Units**: total amount of product units sold in month

**Max**: max amount of product units sold per order

**Min**: min amount of product units sold per order

**Avr**: average amount of product units sold per order

I want to achieve following grouping (LINQ example):

```
list
.GroupBy(x => new { x.ProductId, x.TimeStamp.Year, x.TimeStamp.Month })
.Select(x => new ProductStats
{
    ProductId  = x.Key.ProductId,
    Year = x.Key.Year,
    Month = x.Key.Month,

    Units = x.Sum(y => y.Quantity),
    Max = x.Max(y => y.Quantity)
    Min = x.Min(y => y.Quantity),
    Avg = (int)Math.Ceiling(x.Average(y => y.Quantity)),
})
```

My projection looks like:

```
Projection = Sitecore.Processing.Engine.Projection.Projection.Of<Interaction>()
                .CreateTabular("ProductStats",
                interaction => interaction.Events.OfType<PurchaseInvoiceOutcome>(),
                cfg => cfg

                .Key("ProductId", x => x.ProductId)
                .Key("Year", x => x.Timestamp.Year)
                .Key("Month", x => x.Timestamp.Month)
                    .Measure("Count", x => 1)
                    .Measure("Units", x => x.Quantity)
                    //.Measure("Max", x => Min(x.Quantity))
                    //.Measure("Min", x => Max(x.Quantity))
                    //.Measure("Avr", x => Average(x.Quantity))
                );
```

As I know *"Measure"* property can only calculates sum of grouping items.
As a workaround I can calculate **Average** by projecting **Count** and **Units** and then calculate *Units/Count*.

But I have no idea how to calculate **Min** and **Max**. I know that as a workaround I can remove grouping in projection and move this part of job to training worker, but I don`t want to increase projection data set.

Do you have any suggestions how to implement above scenario? Any advice would be much appreciated.